# Streams is recreating stores quite often

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

In a streams application I'm using interactive queries and statestores in order to scale and be able to consume data from topics more quickly. However quite often I see warnings in the logs:

```
anomaly-timeline-3                    | 2019-03-01 08:43:58,177 INFO 
anomaly-timeline-a3b6b7d6-3bd8-40a6-b070-874964bed3ee-StreamThread-2 org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread stream-thread [anomaly-timeline-a3b6b7d6-3bd8-40a6-b070-874964bed3ee-StreamThread-2] Reinitializing StandbyTask TaskId: 1_0
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         ProcessorTopology:
anomaly-timeline-3                    |                 KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000012:
anomaly-timeline-3                    |                         topics:         [anomaly-timeline-two-minutes-error-score-repartition]
anomaly-timeline-3                    |                         children:       [KSTREAM-REDUCE-0000000009]
anomaly-timeline-3                    |                 KSTREAM-REDUCE-0000000009:
anomaly-timeline-3                    |                         states:         [two-minutes-error-score]
anomaly-timeline-3                    | Partitions [anomaly-timeline-two-minutes-error-score-repartition-0]
anomaly-timeline-3                    |  from changelogs [anomaly-timeline-two-minutes-error-score-changelog-0]
anomaly-timeline-3                    | 2019-03-01 08:43:58,474 INFO anomaly-timeline-a3b6b7d6-3bd8-40a6-b070-874964bed3ee-StreamThread-2 org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher [Consumer clientId=anomaly-timeline-a3b6b7d6-3bd8-40a6-b070-874964bed3ee-StreamThread-2-restore-consumer, groupId=] Resetting offset for partition anomaly-timeline-two-minutes-error-score-changelog-0 to offset 14787709.
anomaly-timeline-3                    | 2019-03-01 08:48:57,991 WARN anomaly-timeline-a3b6b7d6-3bd8-40a6-b070-874964bed3ee-StreamThread-2 org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread stream-thread [anomaly-timeline-a3b6b7d6-3bd8-40a6-b070-874964bed3ee-StreamThread-2] Updating StandbyTasks failed. Deleting StandbyTasks stores to recreate from scratch. org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException: Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions: {anomaly-timeline-one-hour-error-score-changelog-0=14818811}
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseCompletedFetch(Fetcher.java:1002)
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:508)
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1259)
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1187)
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1154)
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeUpdateStandbyTasks(StreamThread.java:1099)
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:846)
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:767)
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:736)
anomaly-timeline-3                    |
anomaly-timeline-3                    | org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException: Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions: {anomaly-timeline-one-hour-error-score-changelog-0=14818811}
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseCompletedFetch(Fetcher.java:1002)
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:508)
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1259)
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1187)
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1154)
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeUpdateStandbyTasks(StreamThread.java:1099)
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:846)
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:767)
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:736)
anomaly-timeline-3                    | 2019-03-01 08:48:57,995 INFO anomaly-timeline-a3b6b7d6-3bd8-40a6-b070-874964bed3ee-StreamThread-2 org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread stream-thread [anomaly-timeline-a3b6b7d6-3bd8-40a6-b070-874964bed3ee-StreamThread-2] Reinitializing StandbyTask TaskId: 3_0
anomaly-timeline-3                    |         ProcessorTopology:
anomaly-timeline-3                    |                 KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000022:
anomaly-timeline-3                    |                         topics:         [anomaly-timeline-one-hour-error-score-repartition]
anomaly-timeline-3                    |                         children:       [KSTREAM-REDUCE-0000000019]
anomaly-timeline-3                    |                 KSTREAM-REDUCE-0000000019:
anomaly-timeline-3                    |                         states:         [one-hour-error-score]
anomaly-timeline-3                    | Partitions [anomaly-timeline-one-hour-error-score-repartition-0]
anomaly-timeline-3                    |  from changelogs [anomaly-timeline-one-hour-error-score-changelog-0]
anomaly-timeline-3                    | 2019-03-01 08:48:58,303 INFO anomaly-timeline-a3b6b7d6-3bd8-40a6-b070-874964bed3ee-StreamThread-2 org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher [Consumer clientId=anomaly-timeline-a3b6b7d6-3bd8-40a6-b070-874964bed3ee-StreamThread-2-restore-consumer, groupId=] Resetting offset for partition anomaly-timeline-one-hour-error-score-changelog-0 to offset 14818854.
```

So it seems for some reason Kafka is reinitializing a standbytask and then fails in updating it. This probably causes stores to be recreated from scratch if I understand the logging.

So my questions are:

- Even though these are warnings, it seems kafka is not running as it should. Is this assumption correct?
- Why is this StandbyTask failing?
- Is it deleting my actual changelogs state stores?
- Should I and how to configure the reset policy for this stream thread?
- Why is it resetting offset for this changelog?

Comment: Hi. How many partitions do you have on your source topic? And how did you configure  ´ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG´ in the KafkaStream app?

Comment: Well the source topic, topic that is being used to aggregate data and put it into changelogs / local state stores, contains 9 partitions. The consumerConfig auto_offset_reset is set to earliest.

Comment: What version are you using? Are your stores updated frequently? From your question, it seems that you load the data once and than the app might actually not get new updates for a longer time?

Comment: Matthias, we are running kafka version 2.0.1. There is a continuous flow of data added to the topic. Then there is a streams setup in place that does a map to change keys, groupByKey, reduce and a materialize. The changelog topics and state stores are updated within their windows (muliple windows with durations 2 minutes, 15 minutes, 12 hours, 1 day). So the app is getting new data continuously, but once the windows get closed, they are not updated. They are read though by a ui on request of a user

Comment: Seems I did not read the question carefully enough...

Answer (score 0):

> Even though these are warnings, it seems kafka is not running as it should. Is this assumption correct?

Yes.

> Why is this StandbyTask failing?

It seems that the StandbyTask fetched from an invalid offset. It's not really failing though.

> Is it deleting my actual changelogs state stores?

For this case, only the local store is deleted, the changelog topic is not affected. The local store is deleted because it's out-of-sync with the changelog topic. This allows to start re-creating the store from scratch.

> Should I and how to configure the reset policy for this stream thread?

You cannot configure the reset policy for the restore consumer. If the above happens, Kafka Streams delete the local store and `seeksToBeginning()` on the changelog topic to recreate the store from scratch.

> Why is it resetting offset for this changelog?

Maybe the StandbyTask lags behind?

You can try to enable TRACE logging for `org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager`. Offsets of StandyTasks are tracked in a local checkpoint file, that is written on commit. The offsets are logged on commit:

```
log.trace("Writing checkpoint: {}", this.checkpointableOffsets);
```

This should help to figure out, if a StandbyTask falls behind. For this case, maybe you need more thread or more instances to avoid this.